# Bitwise Operations and not logical

Tags: bit-manipulation

I'm new to computer science and recently took a class. I'm struggling with this question which i don't quiet understand though i'm aware of bitwise operations

Question image: [image]

Can I have a clear explanation please ?

Comment: You will always receive good results at Stack Overflow, but [MATHEMATICS](http://math.stackexchange.com/) might be good place to ask this kind of question as well ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer: B

### Explanation:

Use DeMorgan's Laws (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

```
NOT (A and B) = (NOT A) or (NOT B)
NOT (A or B) = (NOT A) and (NOT B)
```

Following this logic:

The diagram represents

```
NOT ( NOT (male and adult male) and NOT (female and minor female) )
```

`NOT (male and adult male)` is satisfied as long as you are `NOT adult male` and thus can be replaced by this. Similarly, `NOT (female and minor female)` can be replaced by `NOT minor female`

Thus:

```
NOT ( (NOT adult male) and (NOT minor female) )
```

Using DeMorgan's law, this becomes:

```
adult male or minor female
```

We can see that this matches answer B.

Comment: I didn't see it from this point, but you explanation is way more analytical and easier understandable than mine. I would recommend it to everyone.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is b). For instance in the left bottom box, the adult male is not allowed. Since the result of this box is not allowed on the upper level, the opposite of the allowed must be the very solution. The same needs to be done for the right box.

a) and c) don't work, because they result in true for either of the lower boxes. d) doesn't work, because 'minor male' for instance would be allowed in both lower boxes, hence the and condition in the upper box would give true and the negation would make it false.

This is a very simple explanation that makes the point clear without using too complex algebra stuff...

Comment: may be a little more explanation please, i don't quiet get it :(

Comment: See the solution of Aristocrates. It is easier to follow, I think.

Answer (score 2):

So it appears to be asking which of (a)–(d) is equivalent to the logic diagram. You can answer that direcrly from theblogic or by deduction via counter examples.

Suppose the 'male' box is M, the 'adult male' aM, the box that surrounds those is MM, the corresponding three on the other side are F, mF and FF, and the one at the top is C.

It's not (a) because an adult male would satisfy the diagram:

```
M = yes
aM = yes
M and aM = yes, so not M and aM = no, so MM = no
F = mF = no
F and mF = no, no not F and mF = yes, so FF = yes
MM and FF = no, so not that = yes, so C = yes
```

It's not (c) by corresponding logic.

It's not (d) because we already know that adult male works.

That leaves (b).

Working the other way around, you need either zero or one of MM and FF to be 'yes' to satisfy the constraint. If the person must be male or female then you can't achieve zero as MM is always yes if the gender is female and vice versa.

So what sort of male ensures MM is 'no' and what sort of female ensures FF is 'no'? The answer is whichever matches both local conditions.